# Three.js - Creating shadows with MeshFaceMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have tried a few different lights now (Directional, Spot, Point), but none of them produce a nice shadow on MeshFaceMaterial objects. Instead, the entire MeshFaceMaterial object will become black.

[My Test Website](http://tishmanconstruction.github.io/test-website/) (please view with a grain of salt, constantly being changed).

How can I use lights to create shadows on MeshFaceMaterials? Does MeshFaceMaterial support shadows? The [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/PointLight) says "Affects objects using MeshLambertMaterial or MeshPhongMaterial."

Here is sample code of how I am loading .json model.

```
loader.load('sample-concrete.js', function ( geometry, materials ) {  
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials )
    );

    mesh1.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add( mesh1 );
});
```

and here is a sample of the material from  my .json file.

```
"materials": [
{
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName"  : "Steel",
"colorDiffuse"  : [0.3059, 0.0471, 0.0471],
"colorAmbient"  : [0.3059, 0.0471, 0.0471],
"colorSpecular"  : [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],
"transparency"  : 1.0,
"specularCoef"  : 25.0,
"vertexColors" : false
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: First `HemisphereLight` does not support shadows. Only `DirectionalLight` and `SpotLight`. Then all your `.castShadow` are false so they will never cast a shadow.

Comment: Yes, I know HemisphereLight does not support shadows. DirectionalLight and SpotLight do not work with MeshFaceMaterial though.

Comment: Seems to me like it is casting shadows. @gaitat, you should put your comment as an answer I think.

Comment: My comment above about DirectionalLight and SpotLight not working was incorrect. They do appear to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MeshFaceMaterial` is just a collection of materials. So if your `materials` variable contains `MeshLambertMaterial` or `MeshPhongMaterial` you should be fine. Shadows will be generated from a `DirectionalLight` or a `SpotLight`.

Just make sure your renderer has:

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
```

your light has:

```
light.castShadow = true;
```

each one of your meshes:

```
mesh.castShadow = true;
```

and you have at least one object (a plane for example) where you do:

```
plane.receiveShadow = true;
```

Comment: This correct answer. I turned the shadow for the windows off.

Comment: Actually what I have now noticed is that the MeshFaceMaterial always casts shadows as intended. However, sometimes the MeshFaceMaterial will turn completely black. I'm not sure if it is because I am using JSONLoader (and Mr. Doob is looking to deprecate it).

The shaders work correctly on my iPhone. iPad, and Macbook Air. But the object appears to be all black on my Lenovo W520 in Chrome and Firefox. It does work on IE though.

Comment: So the Lenovo does not support a feature or an extension the others do. You might want to take a look at http://webglreport.com/ to see what is supported on each machine.